# uploading NSData using AFNetwork terminating my APP

Tags: afnetworking, nsdata, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I'm trying to upload a NSData which is image using AFNetwork but something going wrong which i cannot find where is my mistake

here is my code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"], 0.1);

NSMutableDictionary *postParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"this is only a test post for \"app\".", @"app",
                                   @"this POST for \"test\". ", @"test", nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://url/upload.php" parameters:postParm constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" ];
} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSProgress *progress = nil;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

and the crash result is this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -streamStatus only defined for abstract class.  Define -[AFMultipartBodyStream streamStatus]!'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x019d91e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x017588e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x019d8fbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
>       3   Foundation                          0x01433b3b NSRequestConcreteImplementation + 218
>       4   Foundation                          0x0143b746 -[NSStream(NSStream) streamStatus] + 48
>       5   readWritePlist                      0x000333a1 -[AFMultipartBodyStream open] + 49
>       6   CoreFoundation                      0x0199ac44 CFReadStreamOpen + 116
>       7   CFNetwork                           0x026f395d _ZN30CoreReadStreamFromCFReadStream16_streamImpl_OpenEP13CFStreamErrorPh + 53
>       8   CFNetwork                           0x027c5ae6 _ZThn60_N30CoreReadStreamFromCFReadStream16_streamImpl_OpenEP13CFStreamErrorPh + 34
>       9   CFNetwork                           0x026d1112 _ZN14CoreStreamBase21_streamInterface_OpenEv + 72
>       10  CFNetwork                           0x026f2c34 _ZN17HTTPNetConnection19prepareTransmissionEP17HTTPNetStreamInfoP17__CoreWriteStream + 1614
>       11  CFNetwork                           0x026f2063 _ZN17HTTPNetConnection19requestStateChangedEPvN13NetConnection5StateEP13CFStreamError + 415
>       12  CFNetwork                           0x026f21fd _ZN13NetConnection18scheduleNewRequestEP13_CFNetRequestS1_h + 293
>       13  CFNetwork                           0x026f1da4 _ZN13NetConnection7enqueueEPvh + 538
>       14  CFNetwork                           0x026f1b26 _ZN17HTTPNetStreamInfo16_streamImpl_OpenEP13CFStreamErrorPh + 104
>       15  CFNetwork                           0x02756846 _ZThn60_N17HTTPNetStreamInfo16_streamImpl_OpenEP13CFStreamErrorPh + 34
>       16  CFNetwork                           0x026d1112 _ZN14CoreStreamBase21_streamInterface_OpenEv + 72
>       17  CFNetwork                           0x026f1315 _ZN12HTTPProtocol10openStreamEv + 267
>       18  CFNetwork                           0x0276498c _ZN12HTTPProtocol26useNetConnectionForRequestEP13NetConnectionP15__CFHTTPMessageh + 1550
>       19  CFNetwork                           0x026f05d8 _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry28dispatchConnectionToProtocolEP13NetConnectionP12HTTPProtocolP18HTTPRequestMessageh + 284
>       20  CFNetwork                           0x026f03b9 _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry34notifyNextProtocolOfOpenConnectionEP13NetConnectionh + 349
>       21  CFNetwork                           0x026ed71d _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry25enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage + 637
>       22  CFNetwork                           0x026ed0db _ZN19HTTPConnectionCache34_onqueue_enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage + 185
>       23  CFNetwork                           0x0276a897 ___ZN19HTTPConnectionCache25enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage_block_invoke + 35
>       24  CoreFoundation                      0x0197ac69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
>       25  CFNetwork                           0x026e8441 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 155
>       26  CFNetwork                           0x027ca3f4 _ZThn16_N19RunloopBlockContext24multiplexerClientPerformEv + 20
>       27  CFNetwork                           0x026e8257 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 299
>       28  CFNetwork                           0x026e806c _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 76
>       29  CoreFoundation                      0x0196277f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
>       30  CoreFoundation                      0x0196210b **CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
>       31  CoreFoundation                      0x0197f1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
>       32  CoreFoundation                      0x0197e9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
>       33  CoreFoundation                      0x0197e7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
>       34  Foundation                          0x01353ece +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 381
>       35  Foundation                          0x013afa07 -[NSThread main] + 76
>       36  Foundation                          0x013af966 __NSThread__main** + 1275
>       37  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0241d5fb _pthread_body + 144
>       38  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0241d485 _pthread_struct_init + 0
>       39  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x02422cf2 thread_start + 34
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

any idea what is my mistake here..!?

Answer (score 6):

After I update AFNetwork to latest version which is 2.3.1, problem got solved.

Comment: Check this issue for more about this. 
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2128